# How to change img width but keep original height in css?

Tags: html, css, image

In css, how can I change an image width to be twice as big, but keep the height the same as the original height?

I tried

```
img {
    width : 400px;
    height : auto;
}
```

It should work for IE11+. Also The images are being dynamically loaded, so I don't know the original height, but I know the width (its an specified parameter).

but it does not work

Comment: What is the original height of the image? You could try `img { width: 400px; min-height: {image-height}px; }`. It'll distort your image but prevent the height from automatically scaling. This will only work though if you know the height of the specific image ahead of time.

Comment: I can't hardcode the original height in the css.

Answer (score 0):

Twice as big or exactly 400px wide?

To make it twice (or whatever `x` times bigger or smaller) you could use CSS3 `scale` transformation.

```css
img {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

This will grow the image in place in all directions so maybe you also want to move it a bit:

```css
img {
  transform: scale(2) translate(25%, 25%);
}
```

See [CSS3 transform functions](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp). Pretty useful.

Comment: Basically I just want to scale in 1 dimension, but keep the other dimension the same, but not hardcode the height in the css. And it should be for IE11+.

Comment: @omega IE supports CSS transforms from version 9.

Comment: Can I use transform scale but provide pixels?

Comment: `transform: scale(2, 1);` will make it 2x wide and keep 1x height. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

your css code is correct

check the orginal size of your image

or display or width of his parent

```css
img{
  width: 400px;
}
```

always you must just set your width for images and height of image automatically set Proportional of original size of picture